# Subtraction float field odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How in function subtraction two float field "Finish - Start"

```
start = fields.Float(string='Star')
finish = fields.Float(string='Fin')
total = fields.Float(string='Total')

    @api.one
       def total_sum(self):
       ??????
```

Comment: Can you please get in more detail with your question? It is hard to answer in this broad context.

Comment: @CZoellner I need simple solution, from excel import start and finish date (start: 08:00:00, finish: 16:00:00) after import over odoo in field total I need result finish - start (08:00). I don't need how set field datetime or float or string and than convert to time. Any solution? Also is it possible after import start and finish automaticly populate field total if start and finish not empty?

Comment: What about defining the new field in Odoo and then get the correct results in the excel file already?

Comment: @CZoellner Please see what I want https://postimg.org/image/o8no7if07/

Comment: Yes, i already got it. But my point with doing the math already in excel stands! If you don't need onchange/compute behaviour in Odoo, that should be enough.

Comment: @CZoellner sometimes field finish may be empty, I need through odoo form view  populate value.

Comment: OK, now my point not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like that,

```
total = fields.Float(string='Total', compute=_set_total)

@api.multi
def _set_total(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.total = float(rec.finish or 0.0) - float(rec.start or 0.0)
```

However you can also create that field normal not functional

```
total = fields.Float(string='Total')

@api.onchange('finish','start')
def _set_total(self):
    self.total = float(self.finish or 0.00) - float(self.start or 0.00)
```

Comment: Hi, after run your code get error  --> https://postimg.org/image/5y4cfucn1/

Comment: Is onchange triggered on import? I would use `@api.depends` for that functionality on the first mentioned method. And i think `time1 - time2` will return a `datetime` object. So you need to handle that for the final float value. And for later hints: on the view the field `total` should use the widget `float_time`.

Comment: If you want result in float time then you should look at this answer and try this, please update field name and other required things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148952/convert-char-to-datetime-odoo-9/41156758#41156758

Comment: @Empro Tech this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148952/convert-char-to-datetime-odoo-9/41156758#41156758 work fine onchange. I'm try add compute but return https://postimg.org/image/otxr969fj/ Is it possible?

Comment: You just need to add loop, because in self you are getting browsable records list. See I have updated the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148952/convert-char-to-datetime-odoo-9/41156758#41156758

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.  Tnx fork fine, but in tree view don't show sum total minutes https://postimg.org/image/j76ba1ytj/

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Here is new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165486/sum-times-odoo-9

Comment: I have posted answer for that question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def total_sum(self, cr, uid, ids, start, finish, context=None):
    res = {}
    res['total'] = finish - start
    return {'value': res}
```