# Convert char to datetime odoo 9

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, open-source, odoo-9

I have two char fields, data import from excel or csv in odoo.

```
time_1= fields.Char(string = 'Time 1')
time_2= fields.Char(string = 'Time 2') 
result= fields.Float(string = 'Result Time 2 - Time 1')  #Need result 06:00
```

time_1 = 10:00:00,
time_2 = 16:00:00 (data from external source)

How with @api.onchange('time_1', 'time_2') or @api.depends('time_1', 'time_2')

convert char to time and subtract time_2 - time_1 and put result in result field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like that,

```
from datetime import datetime

@api.multi
@api.onchange('time_1', 'time_2') 
def onchange_time(self):
    for rec in self:
        time1 = datetime.strptime(rec.time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        time2 = datetime.strptime(rec.time2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        rec.result = (time2 - time1).seconds / float(60*60)
```

> Two **datetime** objects will return **timedelta** obect in result
>   while you perform any arithmetic operations on it. timedelta has
>   property while will give you difference in seconds, so you can convert
>   that seconds to hours.

And then in view set

```
<field name="result" widget="float_time" />
```