# Sum times odoo 9

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9, odoo

When use compute  in tree view sum is not visible. When use onChange sum is visible any solution how fix it. I need compute after insert data from .csv automaticly populate time_total fields.

Example:

[image: Example]

Source:

```
class my_data(models.Model):
    _name = "my.data"
    _description = "My Data"


    user = fields.Char(string = 'User')
    date = fields.Date(string = 'Date')
    start_time = fields.Datetime(string='Start', placeholder="Start", default="2016-01-01 00:00:00.624139")
    finish_time = fields.Datetime(string='Finish', placeholder="Finish", default="2016-01-01 00:00:00.624139")
    total_time = fields.Float(string='Total minutes', placeholder="Total", compute='onchange_time')
    #total_time = fields.Float(string='Total minutes', placeholder="Total minutes")



    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('start_time', 'finish_time')
    def onchange_time(self):
        for rec in self:
            time1 = datetime.strptime(rec.start_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            time2 = datetime.strptime(rec.finish_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            rec.total_time = (time2 - time1).seconds / float(60*60)
```

*SHOW SUM IN TREE VIEW WHEN MANUAL CHANGE VALUE IN FORM VIEW*

```
 @api.onchange('start_time', 'finish_time') 
    def onchange_time(self):
        time1 = datetime.strptime(self.start_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        time2 = datetime.strptime(self.finish_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.total_time = (time2 - time1).seconds / float(60*60)
```

Comment: Please include your code, output and expected output in your question; don't link to it.

Comment: @Evert source code is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do one change in that,

Store that field in database and it will show you the sum of that field.

```
total_time = fields.Float(string='Total minutes', placeholder="Total", compute='onchange_time', store=True)
```

And then remove onchange and insted use depends

```
@api.depends('start_time', 'finish_time') 
def onchange_time(self):
    time1 = datetime.strptime(self.start_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    time2 = datetime.strptime(self.finish_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    self.total_time = (time2 - time1).seconds / float(60*60)
```

> There is reason behind that scenario is, group by operation required
>   field in database because odoo frameworks prepared query for group by
>   and then get result back from the database. So if the field is not there
>   in database then how it can show you result.